Where is the following Upanishad verse found?
There is an Upanishad verse. "You have become the girl. You have become the old man etc".I read it few years ago where is it found?

The Upanishad verse given below might be the verse you are looking for.

"You are the woman, You are the man, You are the boy, (and) You are
the girl too. You are the old man tottering with a stick. Taking
birth, You have Your faces everywhere."

(Svetasvatara Upanishad 4.3)

Thanks for the answer Sir

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/60615/i-had-converted-to-islam-can-i-be-hindu-again kindly answer sir

Of course you can come back to Hinduism. In fact you should just consider yourself a Hindu. How would you lose your Hindu-ness just because you recited the shahada in front of an Imam? The Shahada means nothing to a Hindu. If you feel very strongly that you should ritualistically return to the Hindu fold then contact VHP, ISKCON, Arya Samaj. They do Shuddhi ceremony. Many Muslims, Christians convert to Hinduism every year.

Please quote references sir thanks

You can go through Devala Smriti given here: https://archive.org/details/devala-smriti/mode/2up

I have gone through it..It mentions only about those who have been taken away by force..not wilful people
