I had converted to Islam can I be Hindu again?
Few days ago I had become a Muslim.Although I never ate any meat or performed namaz etc..I did a sankalpa that I am a Muslim..Now I have a few doubts..Have I become a Mleccha(as Usana smriti says I have discarded my duties) or a Pakhandi/Heretic(as Vedas are the only truth and non vedic docrines and religions are false(Manu smriti 12.94-95)..Is there any prayaschitta for one who wilfully leaves the vedic religion(due to ignorance and not force(As Devala smriti recommends expitiation for those abducted by Mlecchas also Pakhanda can be condoned in case of adversity..according to some purana I dont remember)..I want to know is there expitiation for someone who has wilfully become a Muslim(Pakhandi)?
Kindly quote references thanks..

If you have devotion to God you can ignore smriti injunctions (Read Narada Bhakti sutra verse 2). Arunagirinathar the great skanda saint was a womanizer before he became Skanda devotee. Don't think about the past. Obviously by smriti standards even if you didn't get converted to Islam you are still a sinner I think.

There are various prayaschittas for illicit sex but is there expitiation for pasandavada/heresy

It is not verse 2 but verse 8 of Narada Bhakti Sutra

Do naam japa and don't do it again
